# How can my add-in listen to events from another add-in in Office/Word application?

Tags: c#, events, ms-word, word-addins, imanage

I have a Word add-in that listens to `DocumentBeforeClose` event so that when the user closes Word, I will automatically save the document so there will be no save prompt. I'm having issues when an iManage add-in is enabled in Word because it also prompts a save dialog when user hits close button, I want to suppress that save prompt.

I have tried to get the add-ins using `addins = Application.COMAddIns` and try to set `addin.Connect = false;` to temporarily disable the add-in and later enable it after document closed, but I cannot due to admin rights.

How can I use the `addin.Object` to register to iManage add-in's `DocumentBeforeClose` event like hijacking it?

NOTE: Word's `DocumentBeforeClose` event gets fired after the iManage save prompt so I need to save the document in iManage add-in `DocumentBeforeClose` event to prevent the save prompt from appearing.

Comment: Your add-ins must be written in a coding language and the solution you seek would be for that language. You may find it helpful to your cause if you would specify that language in the tags you attached to your question. I am also fascinated by your reference to the `iManage` add-in and wonder if a solution can be found without seeing its code. My approach would be to presume that no events can be prevented from occurring. Therefore I would try to disqualify particular occurrences from responding to them, such as setting a switch somewhere.

Comment: I have added c# tag thanks. I was thinking if maybe the events of my add-in can be prioritized based on the order of how the add-ins are loaded which I think is alphabetically. But I am not sure if it affects the event order at all. If it's possible to prioritize the event I can simply make my add-in's DocumentBeforeClose the priority then save the document, by the time iManage add-in's event will be hit, document will then be saved and no prompt will occur. Trying it but I'm not sure it works.

Comment: Events occur in strict order. The computer deals with them as they occur and so must your program.

Comment: According to this article [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/909f61b4-670f-4475-af4a-f6c28d8d67b4/how-to-change-the-order-of-loading-addins?forum=exceldev) 

_But based on the experience of dealing with add-ins, Outlook loads add-ins in the alphabetical order of their ProgIDs. The events are fired in the reverse order._

Comment: Update: renaming my add-in ( "zz<add-in name>")  to be loaded last so events will be fired first to test the theory, but it did not work :(